# p:printer does not work

Tags: primefaces, printing

I'm using PF 5.3 on Glassfish 4.1. I need a printer functionality. But I just can not get even this simple example work. Everything else is just working fine. The button and the image from the following example are being rendered, but `p:printer` is not working. What I'm doing wrong? Could it be a some kind of configuration issue?

```
<h:body>
  <p:graphicImage id="img" value="/resources/img/test/datatable.png" />

  <h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Print Image" type="button">
        <p:printer target="img" />
    </p:commandButton>
  </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: missing `h:head`?  (in fact you miss an [mcve])

Comment: Thanks! Indeed **h:head** was missing. Now it works :)

Comment: Then you most likely had many other issues as well, including errors in the browser console

Comment: Yes, that could be the case. I'm going to check my other JSF templates. Once again - a big thanks to you for that prompt and helpful answer!

Comment: You are welcome... Remember you can 'accept' the answer ;-) (and checking the browser console when things 'do not work' helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an `h:head` in your page for javascript resources to be loaded. These are needed for the `p:commandButton` and `p:printer` to work.